# How to use the cadata argument in load_verify_locations?

Tags: python-2.7, ssl-certificate

I need to make an ssl context with an in-memory CA root certificate. I assume this is done by using the method load_verify_locations(cadata=). But whatever I try I'm getting the error "nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:2903)".

Can somebody enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong ?

It works when providing a file name. However, the file contains the very same data as the string PEM variable.

The Python script will run on an environment w/o writing access to the local file system. So I can't write the PEM string into a temporary file. Hence my requirement to pass the root certificate as a string variable. It must run on Python 2.7, using only the standard libraries.

I've tried various ways of encoding/decoding, but that didn't work out either.

The script runs on Python 2.7, on Linux Mint 19.1 amd64. openssl-python 17.5.0 is installed. openssl 1.1.1 is installed.

I've made a proof of concept script to test different cases.

First, the CA_STRING string is used for the cadata argument. Which fails.

Second, the CA_STRING string is written into cadata.pem, read back into another string variable and used for the cadata argument. Which also fails.

Third, the name of the file previously created is used for the cafile argument. Which doesn't fail.

Fourth, the strings for the first and second test are compared. Maybe there is some kind of encoding issue here.

```py
# Proof of concept code to investigate the difference between using the cadata and cafile arguments.

import ssl

# Copy/paste from the cadata.pem file
CA_STRING = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
            "MIIDpTCCAo2gAwIBAgIUBdwEtNtRkxog9YXLx73rcUaqwQgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL" \
            "BQAwYjELMAkGA1UEBhMCQkUxETAPBgNVBAgMCEZsYW5kZXJzMRAwDgYDVQQHDAdh" \
            "bnR3ZXJwMQwwCgYDVQQKDANzc2wxDzANBgNVBAsMBnB5dGhvbjEPMA0GA1UEAwwG" \
            "Y2FkYXRhMB4XDTE5MDcxMjA2NDQwOVoXDTM5MDcwNzA2NDQwOVowYjELMAkGA1UE" \
            "BhMCQkUxETAPBgNVBAgMCEZsYW5kZXJzMRAwDgYDVQQHDAdhbnR3ZXJwMQwwCgYD" \
            "VQQKDANzc2wxDzANBgNVBAsMBnB5dGhvbjEPMA0GA1UEAwwGY2FkYXRhMIIBIjAN" \
            "BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA37p+/2uMgnaisgfxUUUPkPKLU48Q" \
            "O+Bhuyrhfb6hacCsPf6vHmGxqKrLnBA9TH/3Qi6dsMeu5AHvhFu6Y3WlnWXWRw0j" \
            "lHCOhWiFcUYxWfp1XMl2VSV5Z0dikgKQAU3H054gngQyLLPCSBtDIFQOktnD4fRc" \
            "BdmJrvxL3ebOksC5BzR3p/UqufhBDjGGZ0PKnWP2IyQUaruhWFGFJNU20GPySq0u" \
            "TLDWbuq+COzgbyEPMyuLAouOyEEC4SOKYgyWKKTvZjxQTjaKgOFGXrl1I2JNHliv" \
            "kJyT0Rdh4swqeK0PgxBDOc0TQk3i8mnOv+5xSvalSRmEfMnihUvpHAiY4QIDAQAB" \
            "o1MwUTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUgao3ocJMrxC9eNzsJKkiNPoHxRQwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU" \
            "gao3ocJMrxC9eNzsJKkiNPoHxRQwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zANBgkqhkiG9w0B" \
            "AQsFAAOCAQEAZH4fiCx1whQcb9lMcWPUpfJHmE6ITs43yIijaqHI8zHoQdi3yiE8" \
            "AEVgWN2SL0O5FgeOiY0t5mRSRHoVZ409bVF60i6CrrsDsic7IQr4HjPXOs9auabT" \
            "UqqDPeZQyVrIpwYQp5Oof8DEugo39su/zOYfBnVB0bzU442RZGkp12EareBZBYdN" \
            "tLta5f1aZxyREbBy+afiY0vX6hk5PUywUvFCiSDWVcMALInMB/NmdpeCIKbeFnfC" \
            "pJ2CqLw1S2P3q1jzuu0pjre3VVlcafj0Y/FOjV1Xks0S6qzCOuvlFPil0rvEczuA" \
            "dIRqYWtpL1KtHCrIT+hijnGLaMnriJ5CDA==\n" \
            "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"


def create_ssl_context():
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    return context


# Use the constant as input
print " (1) Making SSL context with certificate string variable .... ",
try:
    ssl_context = create_ssl_context()
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cadata=CA_STRING)
    print("pass")
except Exception as error:
    print(str(error))

# Use the file content as input
print " (2) Making SSL context with certificate string from file ... ",
try:
    # write the constant into a file
    with open("cadata.pem", "w") as c:
        c.write(CA_STRING)

    # read it back
    with open("cadata.pem", "r") as c:
        ca_file_string = c.read()

    ssl_context = create_ssl_context()
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cadata=ca_file_string)
    print("pass")
except Exception as error:
    print(str(error))


# Use the file name as input
print " (3) Making SSL context with certificate file ............... ",
try:
    ssl_context = create_ssl_context()
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cafile="cadata.pem")
    print("pass")
except Exception as error:
    print(str(error))

# Are the ca constant and file contents identical ?
print " (4) CA variable and file content are identical .............. " + str(CA_STRING == ca_file_string)
```

Running the provided proof of concept script yields the output:

(1) Making SSL context with certificate string variable ....  nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:2903)
 (2) Making SSL context with certificate string from file ...  nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:2903)
 (3) Making SSL context with certificate file ...............  pass
 (4) CA variable and file content are identical .............. True

I expect all the tests to pass. Especially because (3) succeeds with a file written with the very same data.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  If so, would you mind sharing how you did it?  I'm also working on creating the Context using in-memory certs.

Comment: I couldn't make it work completely in-memory. My workaround is to write the data into a temporary file and read it back into memory. The temporary file is erased as soon as it isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that would be the result.  I’ve found a couple of threads related to this in the Python forums which indicated that this is not yet (completely) implemented.  And it looked like the load_verify_locations method itself is just stubbed out without an implementation....oh well, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This was very helpful.

The test script succeeds with Python3 (after updating for 'print()')...

```
$ python3 cert_from_string.py 
 (1) Making SSL context with certificate string variable ....  pass
 (2) Making SSL context with certificate string from file ...  pass
 (3) Making SSL context with certificate file ...............  pass
 (4) CA variable and file content are identical .............  True
```

```
# Proof of concept code to investigate the difference between using the cadata and cafile arguments.
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002351/how-to-use-the-cadata-argument-in-load-verify-locations

# updated for Python3

from __future__ import print_function
import ssl

# Copy/paste from the cadata.pem file
CA_STRING = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
            "MIIDpTCCAo2gAwIBAgIUBdwEtNtRkxog9YXLx73rcUaqwQgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL" \
            "BQAwYjELMAkGA1UEBhMCQkUxETAPBgNVBAgMCEZsYW5kZXJzMRAwDgYDVQQHDAdh" \
            "bnR3ZXJwMQwwCgYDVQQKDANzc2wxDzANBgNVBAsMBnB5dGhvbjEPMA0GA1UEAwwG" \
            "Y2FkYXRhMB4XDTE5MDcxMjA2NDQwOVoXDTM5MDcwNzA2NDQwOVowYjELMAkGA1UE" \
            "BhMCQkUxETAPBgNVBAgMCEZsYW5kZXJzMRAwDgYDVQQHDAdhbnR3ZXJwMQwwCgYD" \
            "VQQKDANzc2wxDzANBgNVBAsMBnB5dGhvbjEPMA0GA1UEAwwGY2FkYXRhMIIBIjAN" \
            "BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA37p+/2uMgnaisgfxUUUPkPKLU48Q" \
            "O+Bhuyrhfb6hacCsPf6vHmGxqKrLnBA9TH/3Qi6dsMeu5AHvhFu6Y3WlnWXWRw0j" \
            "lHCOhWiFcUYxWfp1XMl2VSV5Z0dikgKQAU3H054gngQyLLPCSBtDIFQOktnD4fRc" \
            "BdmJrvxL3ebOksC5BzR3p/UqufhBDjGGZ0PKnWP2IyQUaruhWFGFJNU20GPySq0u" \
            "TLDWbuq+COzgbyEPMyuLAouOyEEC4SOKYgyWKKTvZjxQTjaKgOFGXrl1I2JNHliv" \
            "kJyT0Rdh4swqeK0PgxBDOc0TQk3i8mnOv+5xSvalSRmEfMnihUvpHAiY4QIDAQAB" \
            "o1MwUTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUgao3ocJMrxC9eNzsJKkiNPoHxRQwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU" \
            "gao3ocJMrxC9eNzsJKkiNPoHxRQwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zANBgkqhkiG9w0B" \
            "AQsFAAOCAQEAZH4fiCx1whQcb9lMcWPUpfJHmE6ITs43yIijaqHI8zHoQdi3yiE8" \
            "AEVgWN2SL0O5FgeOiY0t5mRSRHoVZ409bVF60i6CrrsDsic7IQr4HjPXOs9auabT" \
            "UqqDPeZQyVrIpwYQp5Oof8DEugo39su/zOYfBnVB0bzU442RZGkp12EareBZBYdN" \
            "tLta5f1aZxyREbBy+afiY0vX6hk5PUywUvFCiSDWVcMALInMB/NmdpeCIKbeFnfC" \
            "pJ2CqLw1S2P3q1jzuu0pjre3VVlcafj0Y/FOjV1Xks0S6qzCOuvlFPil0rvEczuA" \
            "dIRqYWtpL1KtHCrIT+hijnGLaMnriJ5CDA==\n" \
            "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"


def create_ssl_context():
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    return context


# Use the constant as input
print(" (1) Making SSL context with certificate string variable .... ", end =" ")
try:
    ssl_context = create_ssl_context()
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cadata=CA_STRING)
    print("pass")
except Exception as error:
    print(str(error))

# Use the file content as input
print(" (2) Making SSL context with certificate string from file ... ", end =" ")
try:
    # write the constant into a file
    with open("cadata.pem", "w") as c:
        c.write(CA_STRING)

    # read it back
    with open("cadata.pem", "r") as c:
        ca_file_string = c.read()

    ssl_context = create_ssl_context()
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cadata=ca_file_string)
    print("pass")
except Exception as error:
    print(str(error))


# Use the file name as input
print(" (3) Making SSL context with certificate file ............... ", end =" ")
try:
    ssl_context = create_ssl_context()
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cafile="cadata.pem")
    print("pass")
except Exception as error:
    print(str(error))

# Are the ca constant and file contents identical ?
print(" (4) CA variable and file content are identical .............  " + str(CA_STRING == ca_file_string))
```

Comment: I found this SO post whilst digging into a specific niggle writing my own version of this (using Python 3)... In case it is any use to anyone, I put up a gist: https://gist.github.com/rswift/2b40bda6955bb2a5aabc8f73b82fb5af