# Python Requests - verify ssl certificate without writing to local file

Tags: python, python-requests

I want requests to verify the server's SSL certificate but I'm not willing to write it to the local file system and pass it the file path - rather I prefer providing the base64 of the certificate, or the StringIO stream.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this using the **requests** library?

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be easily possible.  `requests` uses `urllib3` which seems to use the built in `http.client` library.  The `requests` library doesn't support this out of the box, the `urllib3` and `http.client` might but it wasn't clear to me.  If there is another library that you're able to wrap for use in `requests` or if you can get those other libraries to do what you want, you can create a new "Transport Adapter" for requests.  See here for more details: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using [ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations(cadata="...")](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations)

```py
import ssl

import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

base_url = "https://the.website.com"
url = f"{base_url}/resource/x"

# Download the server's PEM (chain) certificate file. It can be downloaded by going to the website
# of the server domain e.g. https://the.website.com and then clicking the browser's security icon.
# From there, view the certificate and download.
ssl_certificate_content = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...<the rest of the certificate content>..."

class SSLContextAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self._certificate_content = kwargs.pop("certificate_content", None)
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        if self._certificate_content:
            ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
            ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cadata=self._certificate_content)
            kwargs['ssl_context'] = ssl_context

        return super().init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)

session = requests.Session()

adapter = SSLContextAdapter(certificate_content=ssl_certificate_content)
session.mount(base_url, adapter)

response = session.request(method="GET", url=url)
```

References:

- https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4032
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64835339/11043825
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282654/11043825
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215614/11043825
- https://medium.com/@menakajain/export-download-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-bcfc41ea46a2
- https://articles.assembla.com/en/articles/1623119-certificate-verification-error-20-unable-to-get-local-user-certificate