# Connecting to Cloud SQL postgres instance with SSL in python

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to a postgres instance I have in cloud sql. I have everything set up and am able to connect to it if ssl encryption is turned off. But now that I have it on I am trying to connect but running into some error.

```
  def run():
    connector = Connector()
    def getconn():
        conn = connector.connect(
            os.getenv("CONNECTION_NAME"),
            "pg8000",
            user = os.getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
            password = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
            db=os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
            ip_type= IPTypes.PRIVATE
        )
        return conn
    pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "postgresql+pg8000://",
        creator=getconn,
   pool.execute("CREATE TABLE........;")
```

All the certs are stored in secret manager as strings so I am using env variables to grab them, which is why I used cadata for example. But running into this error **cadata does not contain a certificate** why is this error coming up?

Comment: What is 'secret manager'?  I know of several things that could go by that description, and I'm sure there are more i don't know of.

Comment: @jjanes gcp secret manager it’s where you can store  API keys, passwords, access keys etc

Comment: On which line of code are you getting this error? Remember that Cloud SQL does not provide you with a public certificate. Verification of the certificate is performed by SQL Server and not your code. The CN does not even match. In your case, the client certificate is used for authentication of the client and not verification of the host. Therefore, do not use host based code.

Comment: @JohnHanley the error occurs here ssl_context.load_verify_locations(cadata=server_ca). I was attempting to follow GCPs example of connecting to Postgres instance via ssl on their examples. I can connect fine with ssl encryption being off but with it being on I need to connect with those certs?

Comment: Which example are you referring to? Normally, I just specify the filenames of the certificates. Your code does not need to verify the certificates, just load them. Cloud SQL will verify them.

Comment: @JohnHanley they are stored in secrets with just the value as a string for me. Here is the example, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy/connect_tcp.py. I am attempting to just load them with those env variables. But get cadata contains no certificate. I used cadata since it takes a str. I’m attempting to just load the values and pass them into connect_args. Am I doing something wrong in code?

Comment: @JohnHanley Also here if you go to the Postgres example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/commit/6d9e108cb005324fb112705f4a43b313b1dce6a6. I am folllowing this but trying to load the certs as strings not filenames

Comment: A GitHub commit is not helpful, provide a link to the example you are using.

Comment: @JohnHanley https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy/connect_tcp.py I’m using this one except they use filenames as well. I am attempting to use strings

Comment: The code you are using requires **path** to the certificate, not **content** of the certificate.

Comment: @JohnHanley oh I see. Any idea of how to just grab the content? I originally though cadata did that but I guess it’s also path of the file.

Comment: The example you link to does not use secret manager.  It recommends that you use secret manager *instead* of what they are doing in that example.

Comment: @jjanes Yes, but I am using secret manager to load env variables and trying to see how to load the content of the cert rather than the file path which the example uses

Comment: You now know what the problem is. Rewrite your code to use Secret Manager.

Comment: @JohnHanley As in dont use SSLContext()? It is grabbing the all the env variables from secrets manager. I have this on cloud run so it is using secret manager unless I am misunderstanding? Or like instead of using ssl_context.load_verify_locations?

Comment: So your code that uses secret manager to populate those environment variables seems to be wrong.  But you didn't show that part of the code.

Comment: The code you have written expects the certificates to be located as files in the local file system. You are trying to load the certificates as strings from the environment.

Comment: @JohnHanley oh ok hmmmm. I’m looking at the SSL python docs. And am a little lost on how exactly to do that so I can have all the certs within ssl_args then just do connect_args=ssl_args. Do you have an idea of this would be accomplished

Comment: The APIs that you are using require specifying files. Write the contents of the certificates to a local file that the driver can read from.

Comment: @JohnHanley was thinking about mounting the files in secret manager. Do you know if there’s some other way to do it where it just grabs the contents of the file instead of file path? I can’t find any much related to that  here was one old post which may help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002351/how-to-use-the-cadata-argument-in-load-verify-locations

Comment: I just read your comment that you are deploying on Cloud Run. SSL client certificates are not required on Cloud Run. The Cloud SQL Auth Proxy is part of Cloud Run and provides encrypted connections to Cloud SQL. In other words, Cloud Run provides the features you are trying to implement in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) to connect to Cloud SQL from Python as it will generate the SSL context for you, meaning no need to manage SSL certificates! It also has additional benefits of not needing to authorize networks etc.

You can find a [code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy/connect_connector.py) for the Python Connector similar to the one you are using for establishing a TCP connection.

There is also an interactive getting started [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/samples/notebooks/postgres_python_connector.ipynb) that will walk you through using the Python Connector without you needing to change a single line of code!

It makes connecting to Cloud SQL both easy and secure.

Comment: I was using this example https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#private-ip_1

Comment: Does this example require ssl^?

Comment: If you use the Python Connector you won't need to manage the SSL certs yourself. In that link you shared the `import ssl` is most likely a typo.

Comment: It looks like this example is not using the python connector right? As it doesnt intialize connection with  connector = Connector()?

Comment: Correct, the Python Connector is still technically in "beta" for a few more weeks before it will be going GA. Until then the docs will show TCP/Unix. The Python Connector is more secure and easy to use, the doc you linked in the near future will be replaced with Python Connector code usage.

Comment: Ok thanks. I updated my code mind taking a look at it? the rest of the code is just me running pool.execute() commands but here is how I am connecting

Comment: Looks good other than one main thing. You don't want to interact with the connection pool through `pool.execute`, you want something like `with pool.connect() as conn:` and then call execute on the connection itself via `conn.execute("CREATE TABLE ...")`. Here is an [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy/app.py#L55-L61) (db is the pool in this case)

Comment: I still am encountering an error  **Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))** are you familiar with it?

Comment: Are you connecting from Cloud Run? You have set `ip_type=IPTypes.PRIVATE` which means your Cloud SQL instance must have a Private IP address on a VPC network to successfully connect and that your Cloud Run service is attached to the same VPC network via a Serverless VPC access connector. Have those steps been accomplished? See [this snippet](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#configure) for details.

Comment: Yes, it is deployed on Cloud run. And my cloud run is connected to the serverless vpc and my instance only has a private ip. When SSL encryption is turned off I can connect to the instance only when its on I have these issues

Comment: That error is usually due to the VPC network configuration I believe. I would maybe check your egress and ingress rules on your VPC network. Is that error with the Python Connector or TCP connection code? I will try and reproduce it on my end.

Comment: It was with python connector. I am able to connect now. I changed my VPC connector configuration in cloud run from route all traffic to route only private IP and that seemed to fix the issue I guess